# Object reference not set in mvc 5 with razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine

I am currently developing an user accounts for a Uni project but I've been struggle with the registration. For some reason when I tried to add some validations, authentications and so on, it suddenly stopped working and I can't understand why. I've been following a lot of examples and hand written codes in some places but once I try to create an account I am getting error message. Here is the error I've been receiving:

[When is executed and tried to make a registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEKJx.png)

and here is the actual code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(UserRegister Account)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new UserAccount { UserName = Account.EmailAddress, Email = Account.EmailAddress};
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, Account.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        return View(Account);
    }
```

if anyone can help me, I would be so happy.

Thank you in advance,
Valentin

Comment: Good point. I was just about to quietly delete what I wrote :)

Comment: `UserManager` is `null`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358044/usermanager-always-null-in-aspnet-identity-2-app

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen for some reason I thought that I remembered `UserManager` being a `static` helper method but then I remembered the pain of implementing one for an oracle 9 db

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)